# Apache Velocity - Access fields recursively inside a loop

Tags: velocity

I have a bucket of beanies. Each beany has a candidate and each candidate wraps an item.

I am trying to do the following (in jstl style) in the Velocity template, but it does not work. It just prints out `$beany.candidate.item.code` as its output for each line.

```
<ul>
#foreach( $beany in $bucket.items )
    <li>$beany.candidate.item.code</li>
#end
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All velocity does is tries to call `beany.candidate`, if that fails it calls `beany.getCandidate()`, and so on, as explained [here](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#properties). Your code is basically equivalent to:

```
beany.getCandidate().getItem().getCode()
```

If you run above code in java would it give you desired result?

Debug it by accessing only first `$beany.candidate`, then `$beany.candidate.item` and so on to see which one fails.

Comment: @Mohamed Strange. Maybe `$bucket.items` is not what you expect?

Comment: You were right. There was a typo in the last part. Checking one 'dot' at a time helped me to find the culprit. Thanks for the help (And apologies for editing/removing my comments while you were trying to answer).